# Diffie Hellman Key Exchange in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I was thinking of implementing Diffie-Hellman on android mobile systems. In this application two sides say A and B generate keys which are later exchanged to get the common secret key.Android provides support for generating the keys but i want to know what would be the most secure to conduct the exchange. If the method used for exchange is not secure it completely defeats the purpose of using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use your web server as a interface, which creates the corresponding public and private key, and uses it for encryption and decryption? Make sure you even encrypt the way the keys which are sent b/w server to application are encrypted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Also does using Bluetooth to transfer the keys if the mobile systems are nearby sound like a good idea?

Comment: Yes, but a web server may make the process transparent, as you don't have to manage bluetooth connectivity always between both the devices. If its a specific set of people who are using this app, and don't have the problem in doing so, that will work too!